# Codeigniter and Bootstrap using WAMP-> forbidden Access

Tags: codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, wamp

Im a newbie working with CodeIgniter/Bootstrap/WAMP. I'm having problems with accessing the folder outside the application folder. Ive wasted several hours trying to fix the issue but to no avail. Have I missed something? Here's what I've done so far.

file directory

```
 www/myapp/application
 www/myapp/system


 www/myapp/components
           components/css
           components/js
           components/images
```

**What I have done**

```
edit the config.php
      $config['rewrite_short_tags'] =TRUE;

set the autoload.php
      $autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

**template.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>PM with BAM</title>
        <meta name ="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>components/css/bootstrap.css" rel ="stylesheet" media="screen"> 
    </head>    
    <body>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>components/js/bootstrap.js"> </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

I tried deleting the .htaccess file in the application and system folder but im still getting the same error.

I already read some examples and related questions but nothings works.
Any help?

Comment: woah woah... if you are using CI why are you using **includes**? Load views properly. You should **NEVER** need an include, or a required in your php code.

Comment: oops..thanks for reminding me. I'll change it.

Comment: also you can pass the path to the resources to the `base_url` function like so: `<?php echo base_url('components/js/bootstrap.js');?>`

Comment: i already did this but i got the same error.

Comment: I finally solved the problem. It has nothing to do with htacces file settings nor with the directory structure.

The files downloaded from bootstrap website are encrypted. I just unchecked the 'Encrypt contents to secure data' option then everything works.

Hope this can help other newbies like me. :)

Comment: remember to accept / upvote answers that help you find a solution.

Answer (score 4):

I finally solved the problem. It has nothing to do with htacces file settings nor with the directory structure. The files downloaded from bootstrap website are encrypted. I just unchecked the 'Encrypt contents to secure data' option then everything works. Hope this can help other newbies like me. :)

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputation to comment under your answer but my situation was almost identical except when I right clicked on the green "dist" file (green means encrypted in windows) and then properties->advanced(under general tab), the Encrypt contents to secure data was unchecked. So I instantly wrote it off the list as something that could be causing my problem. Later after trying a bunch of different solutions I decided to come back and examine your answer more closely. I ended up having to click the "Encrypt contents to secure data" then "OK" then apply to all children etc. and then uncheck it and apply to all children etc.

In short, if "Encrypt contents to secure data" is not checked and your bootstrap file names are colored green do this:

Check "Encrypt contents to secure data" and apply to all children, then uncheck it and apply to all children.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.htaccess` requires the following to omit rewriting of the url for anything you designate images etc;

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [L] 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|components|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Notice how `components`, `robot.txt` and `favicon.ico` are left as omitted items. Just replace as needed, use `|` to separate entries (css, etc;)

Don't use includes, **read** the CI guide, most people that ask questions here can solve them by looking into the guide, very good documentation.

Comment: is this the .htaccess located inside the application folder? because system folder also has an .htaccess file. I thought deleting the htaccess will remove the restriction.

Comment: the .htaccess in the root, don't delete stuff randomly, the file is NOT just for 'restrictions' it manages `mod_rewrite` conditions (like I've outlined).

Comment: i did what you have suggested but it is now throwing a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: you replaced your `.htaccess` contents with what I showed you? It should work if you have `mod_rewrite` enabled on your apache setup. Just check logs for your 500 error source.

Comment: I get ...file permissions deny server access: C:/wamp/www/myapp/components/css/bootstrap.css, referer: http://localhost/myapp/index.php/site/display

Comment: the root folder would be myapp folder right? not the www folder. yes, i have enabled the mod_rewrite on my apache.

Comment: ...yes the root folder of your application where CI sits, it contains main `index.php` file then has `application`, `system` folders